# How can I print the cell name of a dataframe from an Excel file in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

For example: I have a wrong value from the base Excel file (a cell), how can I print "Error in cell C7" in Python? I think I first need to get the index of the cell of the dataframe but then what? My boss is gonna use wrong values (for testing) from the base Excel file that I'll use with the dataframe. I was thinking of making a dictionary of indexes of Pandas and Excel but I don't really know how to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to use Excel-style referencing for a dataframe? That doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Because I take the dataframe and export it to excel and the final user understands Excel but not Pandas.

Comment: Why not then check if the *Excel file* has an error, instead of trying to apply Excel referencing to a dataframe?

Comment: Thank you for the help. Thing is my boss is gonna use an excel with wrong values for testing so I need to print the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved by iterating on the data frame with try-catch statements

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['john', 'joe'], 'age':['20', np.nan]})

col_dict = {df.columns[i]:chr(i+65) for i in range(len(df.columns))}
for i, item in enumerate(df):
    try:
        df.loc[i, 'age'] = int(df.loc[i, 'age'])
    except ValueError:
        print('ERROR at cell: {} - index {}: column: {!r}'.format(col_dict[item]+str(i), i, item))
```

Comment: Thank you but I need the position of the column and the row as in excel for example "A4". I was thinking of making a dictionary of indexes of Pandas and Excel but I think it's hard to do. Any ideas of how to do that? thank you very much.

Comment: You can get this using the following dict - 

```col_dict = {df.columns[i]:chr(i+65) for i in range(len(df.columns))}```

see implementation in my answer above.

Comment: Also, as you might have already noticed, the above script fails when you have more than 26 columns. You might want to check out the get_column_letter function from openpyxl

Answer (score -1):

Try and use conditions for checking if the cell is empty. Also include the try catch statement to catch the Exceptions as shown in below example.

```
import pandas
from os import sep

inputdir = "data"
fname = "sample.csv"

try:
    filename = inputdir + sep + fname
    data = pandas.read_csv(filename)
    if (not data.empty):
       print(data.iloc[0, 0])

except OSError as e:
    print("ERROR: Unable to find or access file:", e)
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you but it really doesn't solve the problem. What about making a dictionary of indexes of Pandas and Excel but I think it's hard to do. Any ideas of how to do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK What kind of data is he going to put whether it is integer or strings or what type of data. Depending on that you can create boudary values and displays errors.